# How could I calculate the product of two spherical harmonics

Tags: spherical-harmonics

For now I have to calculate the product of two spin-weighted spherical harmonics:
$ _{s}Y_{lm}\ \times\  _{s}Y_{lm}^{*}$
What’s the result of this product? Maybe it is a spin-weighted 0 spherical harmonics with some coefficients?

Comment: The result is a real-valued function of $ \theta$ only, which you could get from [this formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin-weighted_spherical_harmonics#Calculating).

Comment: Can you provide a definition?  Do the two functions have the same argument?